# I cannot read the AttributeSet from my XML resources

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to read an AttributeSet from an XML resource file. 
The relevant code is the following:

```
//This happens inside an Activity
        Resources r = getResources();
        XmlResourceParser parser = r.getXml(R.layout.testcameraoverlay);
        AttributeSet as = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);

        int count = as.getAttributeCount(); //count is 0!!??
```

`count == 0`, so Android is not reading any attributes at all!

The XML file(`R.layout.testcameraoverlay`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:text="@string/app_name" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
```

Why can't I read the attributes?

Comment: I haven't worked much with this, but do you know if you start on the root element or if the parser starts before the root element?  I'm wondering if you call getnext if that will move you to the root element or not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was a misunderstanding of the functioning of the parser. After the line:

```
XmlResourceParser parser = r.getXml(R.layout.testcameraoverlay);
```

the parser is at the beginning of the document and hasn't yet read any element, therefore there is no attributeset because the attributes are of course always relative to the current element. So to fix this I had to do the following which is iterating over the elements until I get to "TextView":

```
    AttributeSet as = null;
    Resources r = getResources();
    XmlResourceParser parser = r.getLayout(R.layout.testcameraoverlay);

    int state = 0;
    do {
        try {
            state = parser.next();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }       
        if (state == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            if (parser.getName().equals("TextView")) {
                as = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
                break;
            }
        }
    } while(state != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you need to read the attributes from the **TextView** for example the Text inside the **TextView** or the ID and so on?

I would make it as follows:

```
TextView text_res = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

String text_inTextView;
String id_fromTextView;

text_inTextView = text_res.getText();
id_fromTextView = String.valueOf(text_res.getId());
```

and so on...

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Nope. In this case the TextView doesn't even exist yet, instead it is contained in an XML resource file. I want to read this resource file and create a TextView from it, but I'm not getting any of the attributes.