# How do I dynamically create a TextView with specified attributes?

Tags: java, android

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/online_message"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Onliners:"
    />
```

I want to create a `TextView` the same as the above by:

```
android.widget.TextView.TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

But how do I specify the `attrs` so that it represents the same attributes as the above?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4796124/104015) is close , but is there a way to read ONLY the attributes(no `TextView` tag in xml) and parse as `AttributeSet`?

**UPDATE**

I'm seeking of a way to construct `AttributeSet` programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think **AttributeSet** is better used when engaged together with using xml layout. Otherwise you can create the above required TextView as below:

```
TextView t = new TextView(context);
t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
t.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);
t.setText("Onliners:");
```

Regarding Id, you don't actually need to set it in code since you have reference to the entire object.

Comment: I'm seeking of a **general** way to set **arbitrary**  valid attributes dynamically.

Comment: attributes are provided once via constructor, so you cant have it arbitrary... thats why its supported via xml layout only. However, you may later change the properties of TextView via its setters.