# Adding attributes from xml to a dynamically added ImageButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-xml

I want to dynamically add `ImageButton`s to a layout base on the images in a directory, but I want them all to have the same formatting as specified in an xml file.

I have tried this

```
    XmlPullParser parser = res.getXml(R.layout.imagebuttons);
    AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
    setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(context, attributes));
```

to read this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="90"
    android:layout_height="160" 
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:onClick="zoomImageFromThumb" >
</ImageButton>
```

but am getting this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16602): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package/package.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException:
Binary XML file line #-1: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #-1: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5458)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5411)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at package.ImageButtons.<init>(ImageButtons.java:27)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at package.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1089)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
E/AndroidRuntime(16602):        ... 11 more
```

I'm lost as to how to fix this problem, is there something really obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention "dp" in your xml file's width and height attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp" 
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:onClick="zoomImageFromThumb" >
</ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was something incredibly simple, I was not actually using the parser, I presumed that the AttributesSet did that. This was the answer I used [I cannot read the AttributeSet from my XML resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787565/i-cannot-read-the-attributeset-from-my-xml-resources)